# Disable startup sound mac (Sierra)

Tags: boot, mac, audio, macos-sierra, system-sounds

Is there a way to disable the startup sound with Sierra? I saw that some 3rd party apps and `sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%0` used to be able to work but not past Snow Leopard.